# How to create a copy to clickboard for dynamic buttons

Tags: javascript, django

Hi guys I'm working currently on a little project with django and Js, I want to add a button to copy information to clickboard, the buttons are dynamic and the site where I'm working is not https so i can't use "navigator.clipboard.writeText" at this point i can get the information trough the attributes specified in my button, but I'm a litle bit stuck since i don't really know how to copy the information from the variables to the clickboard, I'm newbie so if someone can help me with this it would be really nice :)

**This is basically the main piece of code**

```
            {% for item in object_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="th-width">{{ item.user.company.name }}</td>
                    <td class="th-width">{{ item.user.user_name }}</td>
                    <td class="th-width">{{ item.user.full_name }}</td>
                    <td class="th-width email-column">{{ item.user.email }}</td>
                    <td class="th-width">{{ item.expire_date }}</td>
                    <td class="th-width">{{ item.avt_version}}</td>
                    <td class="th-width">{{ item.license_avt }}</td>
                    <td class="th-width">{{ item.generated_user.username }}</td>
                    <td class="th-width">
                        <button class="control button copy-btn btn" company-name="{{item.user.company.name}}"  user-name="{{item.user.user_name}}" full-name="{{item.user.full_name}}" email="{{item.user.email}}" expire-date="{{item.expire_date}}">Copy information</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody> 
    </table>
<script>
    const copyBtns = [...document.getElementsByClassName("copy-btn")]
    copyBtns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const companyName = btn.getAttribute("company-name")
        const userName = btn.getAttribute("user-name")
        const fullName = btn.getAttribute("full-name")
        const email = btn.getAttribute("email")
        const expireDate = btn.getAttribute("expire-date")

        console.log(companyName)
        console.log(userName)
        console.log(fullName)
        console.log(email)
        console.log(expireDate)
        
        btn.textContent = "Copied";
        setTimeout(() => {
            btn.textContent = "Copy information";
        }, 1350);

    }));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your onclick event:

```
const content = "the text you want to copy to clipboard";

const newInputEl = document.createElement('textarea');
document.body.appendChild(newInputEl);
newInputEl.value = content;
newInputEl.select();
document.execCommand('copy', false);
newInputEl.remove();
```

The code above will create a temporary textarea, add your content in it, copy it to clipboard and then remove it.